# QML ListView with sections representing first letter of model's name role - sections are not visible

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have QML `ListView`, which shows customers from database via **UeCustomerModel**. Customers are sorted in model via `MySQL` statement. All works fine, but now I want to add `sections` into `ListView`, so the customers are sorted in sections by first letter criteria. Here is my `ListView`:

```
ListView
{
    id: ueCustomersListView

    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignBottom
    Layout.margins: 8

    clip: true

    spacing: 8

    delegate: UeCustomerSelectorDelegate
    {
        ueParamWidth: ueCustomersListView.width
        ueParamHeight: 128

        ueParamImage: "image://ueCustomerModel/"+model.ueRoleImage
        ueParamName: model.ueRoleCustomerName
        ueParamTaxId: model.ueRoleCustomerTaxId
        ueParamCurrentDebt: model.ueRoleCustomerCurrDebt
        ueParamMaxDebt: model.ueRoleCustomerMaxDebt
    }   // delegate

    section.property: model.ueRoleCustomerName // HERE RUNTIME ERROR OCCURS
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
    section.delegate: UeCustomerSelectorSectionDelegate
    {
        ueParamWidth: ueCustomersListView.width
        ueParamHeight: 128

        ueParamName: section
    }   // section.delegate

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        model=ueCustomerModel;
    }   // Component.onCompleted
}   // ListView
```

and here is section delegate:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle
{
    property int ueParamWidth
    property int ueParamHeight
    property string ueParamName

    width: ueParamWidth
    height: ueParamHeight

    color: "#4682b4"

    antialiasing: true
    smooth: true

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8

        spacing: 8

        Text
        {
            color: "#ffffff"

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            antialiasing: true

            text: ueParamName

            font.family: "Courier"
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 12

            clip: true

            textFormat: Text.RichText

            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }   // Text
    }   // RowLayout
}   // Rectangle
```

Now, when `ListView` is shown, there are no sections visible. What did I miss, i.e., how do I correct `section.property: model.ueRoleCustomerName` statement to get alphabetical letters from customers (`A`, `B`, `C`, ...). I want `ListView` to section `delegates` according to **Customer Name** (delivered from database via model) first letter. Also, in mentioned line of code, I get `QML` runtime error `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`. Why?

P.S.: model works perfectly (is fast, can search accross customers using `TextField`), I've tested it 5 times.

According to **user sk2212**'s hint, I've upgraded the code with:

```
    section.property: "ueParamName"
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
    section.delegate: UeCustomerSelectorSectionDelegate
    {
        ueParamWidth: ueCustomersListView.width/2
        ueParamHeight: ueCustomersListView.height/4

        ueParamName: model.ueRoleCustomerName.subString(0,1)
    }   // section.delegate
```

and here is Section `delegate`:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle
{
    property int ueParamWidth
    property int ueParamHeight
    property string ueParamName

    width: ueParamWidth
    height: ueParamHeight

    color: "#4682b4"

    antialiasing: true
    smooth: true

    RowLayout
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 8

        spacing: 8

        Text
        {
            color: "#ffffff"

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

            antialiasing: true

            text: ueParamName

            font.family: "Courier"
            font.bold: true
            font.pointSize: 12

            clip: true

            textFormat: Text.RichText

            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }   // Text
    }   // RowLayout
}   // Rectangle
```

Still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `section.property` as a model data element:

```
delegate: UeCustomerSelectorDelegate
{
    ueParamWidth: ueCustomersListView.width
    ueParamHeight: 128

    ueParamImage: "image://ueCustomerModel/"+model.ueRoleImage
    ueParamName: model.ueRoleCustomerName
    ueParamTaxId: model.ueRoleCustomerTaxId
    ueParamCurrentDebt: model.ueRoleCustomerCurrDebt
    ueParamMaxDebt: model.ueRoleCustomerMaxDebt
    alphabet: model.ueRoleCustomerName.substring(0,1)
}   // delegate

section.property: "alphabet"
```